# What are the rules for the "..." token in the context of variadic templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

In C++11 there are variadic templates like this one:

```
template< class T, class... Args >
unique_ptr<T> make_unique( Args&&... args )
{
    return unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

There are some curiosities about this: The expression `std::forward<Args>(args)...` uses both `Args` and `args` but only one `...` token. Furthermore `std::forward` is a non-variadic template function taking only one template parameter and one argument. What are the syntax rules for that (roughly)? How can it be generalized?

Also: In the function implementation the ellipsis (`...`) is at the end of the expression of interest. Is there a reason that in the template argument list and the parameter list the ellipsis is in the middle?

Comment: Briefly on the second part: When "declaring" a template parameter pack or function parameter pack, the `...` comes before the identifier being introduced.  When using either or both types of packs, the `...` comes after the expression pattern to expand.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

In the context of variadic template, the ellipsis `...` is used to either pack or unpack parameters/arguments in a template definition, depending on the relative position where it appears:

- it *unpacks* the template parameter pack if it appears on the **right** side of an expression (call this expression *pattern* for a moment)
- or it's a *pack* argument if it appears on **left** side of the name:

```cpp
...thing  // pack   : appears as template arguments
thing...  // unpack : appears when consuming the arguments
```

The rule is that whatever *pattern* is on the left side of `...` is repeated — the unpacked patterns (call them *expressions* now) are separated by comma `,`.

It can be best understood by some examples. Suppose you have this function template:

```
template<typename ...T> //pack
void f(T ... args)      //pack
{
   // here are unpack patterns

   g( args... );        //pattern = args
   h( x(args)... );     //pattern = x(args)
   m( y(args...) );     //pattern = args (as argument to y())
   n( z<T>(args)... );  //pattern = z<T>(args)
}
```

Now if I call this function passing `T` as `{int, char, short}`, then each of the function call is expanded as:

```
g( arg0, arg1, arg2 );           
h( x(arg0), x(arg1), x(arg2) );
m( y(arg0, arg1, arg2) );
n( z<int>(arg0), z<char>(arg1), z<short>(arg2) );
```

In the code you posted, `std::forward` follows the fourth pattern illustrated by `n()` function call.

**Note the difference between `x(args)...` and `y(args...)` above!**

---

You can use `...` to initialize an array also as:

```
struct data_info
{
     boost::any  data;
     std::size_t type_size;
};

std::vector<data_info> v{{args, sizeof(T)}...}; //pattern = {args, sizeof(T)}
```

which is expanded to this:

```
std::vector<data_info> v 
{ 
   {arg0, sizeof(int)},
   {arg1, sizeof(char)},
   {arg2, sizeof(short)}
};
```

---

I just realized a pattern could even include access specifier such as `public`, as shown in the following example:

```
template<typename ... Mixins>
struct mixture : public Mixins ...  //pattern = public Mixins
{
    //code
};
```

In this example, the pattern is expanded as:

```
struct mixture__instantiated : public Mixin0, public Mixin1, .. public MixinN
```

That is, `mixture` derives *publicly* from all the base classes.

Comment: Regarding the expression that is matched; It should be the *largest possible* expression, should it not? For instance `x+args...` should be expanded to `x+arg0,x+arg1,x+arg2`, not `x+arg0,arg1,arg2`.

Comment: So the `...` applies to every expandable entity in the pattern.

Comment: @bitmask: Yes. `x+args...` should expand to `x+arg0,x+arg1,x+arg2`, **not** `x+arg0,arg1,arg2`.

Comment: C++1z introduces `(x + ... + args)` for `x + arg0 + arg1 + arg2`.

Comment: @Jarod42: I'll update this answer once C++17 is released.

Comment: Additionally, you can even call a function on each element of a pack: `int a[sizeof...(T)] = {(my_foreach_f(args), 0)...};`

Comment: @synther: `sizeof...(T)` is not needed there. You can simply write : `int a[] = { ___ };`

Comment: @Nawaz Need update for Folding expressions in C++17 ? as per Jarod42 example

Comment: @P0W: Will update it once C++17 is officially released.

Answer (score 51):

The following is taken from the talk ["Variadic Templates are Funadic"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zgq6_zFNGY) by Andrei Alexandrescu at GoingNative 2012. I can recommend it for a good introduction on variadic templates.

---

There are two things one can do with a variadic pack. It's possible to apply `sizeof...(vs)` to get the number of elements and expand it.

## Expansion rules

```
Use            Expansion

Ts...          T1, ..., Tn
Ts&&...        T1&&, ..., Tn&&
x<Ts,Y>::z...  x<T1,Y>::z, ..., x<Tn,Y>::z
x<Ts&,Us>...   x<T1&,U1>, ..., x<Tn&,Un>
func(5,vs)...  func(5,v1), ..., func(5,vn)
```

Expansion proceeds inwards outwards. When expanding two lists in lock-step, they have to have the same size.

#### More examples:

```
gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs)...);
```

Expands all `Ts` in the template argument list of `A` and then the function `hun` gets expanded with all `vs`.

```
gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs...));
```

Expands all `Ts` in the template argument list of `A` and all `vs` as the function arguments for `hun`.

```
gun(A<Ts>::hun(vs)...);
```

Expands the function `hun` with `Ts` and `vs` in lock-step.

#### Note:

`Ts` is not a type and `vs` is not a value! They are aliases for a list of types/values. Either list may be potentially empty. Both obey only specific actions. So the following is not possible:

```
typedef Ts MyList;  // error!
Ts var;             // error!
auto copy = vs;     // error!
```

## Expansion loci

#### Function arguments

```
template <typename... Ts>
void fun(Ts... vs)
```

#### Initializer lists

```
any a[] = { vs... };
```

#### Base specifiers

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct C : Ts... {};
template <typename... Ts>
struct D : Box<Ts>... { /**/ };
```

#### Member initializer lists

```
// Inside struct D
template <typename... Us>
D(Us... vs) : Box<Ts>(vs)... {}
```

#### Tempate argument lists

```
std::map<Ts...> m;
```

Will only compile if there is a possible match for the arguments.

#### Capture lists

```
template <class... Ts> void fun(Ts... vs) {
    auto g = [&vs...] { return gun(vs...); }
    g();
}
```

#### Attribute lists

```
struct [[ Ts... ]] IAmFromTheFuture {};
```

It is in the specification, but there is no attribute that can be expressed as a type, yet.

Comment: Nice. Function arguments are left out of the loci, though :P

Comment: @Potatoswatter Thanks. The expansion in the function argument list was not mentioned.

Comment: @typ1232 Sorry for the edit, but I felt that your original post was too close to plagiarism. Btw, I also watched that talk some time ago -- awesome.