# Expansion with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

What is the difference between the following 3 calls for `gun` function?

```
template <class... Ts> void fun(Ts... vs) {
  gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs)...);
  gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs...));
  gun(A<Ts>::hun(vs)...);
}
```

I am interested in an answer that explains the three calls using a specific example.

Comment: Fun with guns??

Comment: @0x499602D2 Fun gun, hun

Comment: A similar question is this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652412/what-are-the-rules-for-the-token-in-the-context-of-variadic-template , but the answers below more thoroughly clarifies my question, and are more specific

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Originally I just literally answered the question, but I wanted to expand this somewhat to provide a more thorough explanation of how what packs are expanded into what. This is how I think about things anyway.

Any pack immediately followed by an ellipses is just expanded in place. So `A<Ts...>` is equivalent to `A<T1, T2, ..., TN>` and `hun(vs...)` is similarly equivalent to `hun(v1, v2, ..., vn)`. Where it gets complicated is when rather than a pack followed by ellipses you get something like `((expr)...)`. This will get expanded into `(expr1, expr2, ..., exprN)` where `expri` refers to the original expression with any pack replaced with the `i`th version of it. So if you had `hun((vs+1)...)`, that becomes `hun(v1+1, v2+1, ..., vn+1)`. Where it gets more fun is that `expr` can contain more than one pack (as long as they all have the same size!). This is how we implement the standard perfect forwarding model;

```
foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
```

Here `expr` contains two packs (`Args` and `args` are both packs) and the expansion "iterates" over both:

```
foo(std::forward<Arg1>(arg1), std::forward<Arg2>(arg2), ..., std::forward<ArgN>(argN));
```

That reasoning should make it possible to quickly walk through your cases for, say, what happens when you call `foo(1, 2, '3')`.

The first one, `gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs)...);` expands `Ts` "in place" and then there's an expression to expand for the last ellipses, so this calls:

```
gun(A<int, int, char>::hun(1), 
    A<int, int, char>::hun(2), 
    A<int, int, char>::hun('3'));
```

The second one, `gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs...));` expands both packs in place:

```
gun(A<int, int, char>::hun(1, 2, '3'));
```

The third one, `gun(A<Ts>::hun(vs)...)`, expands both packs at the same time:

```
gun(A<int>::hun(1), 
    A<int>::hun(2), 
    A<char>::hun('3'));
```

[update] For completeness, `gun(A<Ts>::hun(vs...)...)` would call:

```
gun(A<int>::hun(1, 2, '3'),
    A<int>::hun(1, 2, '3'),
    A<char>::hun(1, 2, '3'));
```

Finally, there's one last case to consider where we go overboard on the ellipses:

```
gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs...)...);
```

This will not compile. We expand both `Ts` and `vs` "in place", but then we don't have any packs left to expand for the final ellipses.

Answer (score 16):

Here's how they expand when Ts is T, U and vs is t, u:

```
gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs)...) -> gun(A<T, U>::hun(t), A<T, U>::hun(u))
gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs...)) -> gun(A<T, U>::hun(t, u));
gun(A<Ts>::hun(vs)...)    -> gun(A<T>::hun(t), A<U>::hun(u))
```

And one more case you didn't cover:

```
gun(A<Ts>::hun(vs...)...) -> gun(A<T>::hun(t, u), A<U>::hun(t, u))
```

If you run the code below in VS14 you'll get this output:

```
calling gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs)...);
    struct A<int,double>::hun(double);
    struct A<int,double>::hun(int);
    gun(struct A<int,double>, struct A<int,double>);
calling gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs...));
    struct A<int,double>::hun(int, double);
    gun(struct A<int,double>);
calling gun(A<Ts>::hun(vs)...);
    struct A<double>::hun(double);
    struct A<int>::hun(int);
    gun(struct A<int>, struct A<double>);
calling gun(A<Ts>::hun(vs...)...);
    struct A<double>::hun(int, double);
    struct A<int>::hun(int, double);
    gun(struct A<int>, struct A<double>);
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

void printTypes() {}

template<typename T, typename... Ts> void printTypes(T, Ts... vs) {
    cout << typeid(T).name() << (sizeof...(Ts) ? ", " : "");
    printTypes(vs...);
}

template<typename... Ts> struct A {
    template<typename... Us>
    static auto hun(Us... vs) {
        cout << "    " << typeid(A).name() << "::hun(";
        printTypes(vs...);
        cout << ");" << endl;
        return A{}; 
    }
};

template<typename... Ts> void gun(Ts... vs) {
    cout << "    gun(";
    printTypes(vs...);
    cout << ");" << endl;
}

template<typename... Ts> void fun(Ts... vs) {
  cout << "calling gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs)...);" << endl;
  gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs)...);
  cout << "calling gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs...));" << endl;
  gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs...));
  cout << "calling gun(A<Ts>::hun(vs)...);" << endl;
  gun(A<Ts>::hun(vs)...);
  cout << "calling gun(A<Ts>::hun(vs...)...);" << endl;
  gun(A<Ts>::hun(vs...)...);
}

int main() {
    fun(1, 2.0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and for the code example! However, i chose the previous answer as it gave more details.