# How to avoid using the "indices trick" repeatedly?

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, idioms, index-sequence

I have a class named `memory_region`, which is sort of like an untyped `gsl::span` (i.e. it's essentially a `void*` and a `size_t`), which I also use for type erasure. It thus has an `as_span<T>()` method.

With this class, I have a `std::unordered_map<std::string, memory_region> my_map` - which is used to pass type-erased spans between parts of my code which don't share headers, so they can't know about each others' types. The typical access to one of these looks like:

```
auto foo = my_map.at("foo").as_span<bar_t>();
```

This works just fine with code that has a fixed set of buffers and types and names. But - things get tricky when my code's buffers depend on a template parameter pack. Now, I've implemented a

```
std::string input_buffer_name(unsigned input_buffer_index);
```

function, so if I have an index sequence and my parameter pack I can do, for example

```
template<typename Ts..., std::size_t... Indices>
my_function(std::unordered_map<std::string, memory_region>& my map) {
    compute_stuff_with_buffers(
        my_map.at(input_buffer_name(Indices)).as_span<Ts>()...
    );
}
```

(this is a variation on the infamous [indices trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463388/can-someone-please-explain-the-indices-trick); note that the same type may appear more than once in the pack, so I can't "wrap the types in a tuple" and acces it by type.)

The thing is, though - my code doesn't have that index sequence in the template parameters; most of it is templated on just the parameter pack of types. So I find myself writing "helper functions/methods" all the time to be able to use that index sequence, e.g.:

```
template<typename Ts..., std::size_t... Indices>
my_function_helper(
    std::unordered_map<std::string, memory_region>& my map
    std::index_sequence<Indices...>  /* unused */) 
{
    compute_stuff_with_buffers(
        my_map.at(input_buffer_name(Indices)).as_span<Ts>()...
    );
}

template<typename Ts...>
my_function(std::unordered_map<std::string, memory_region>& my map) {
    my_function_helper(
        my_map, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)> {}
    );
}
```

What can I do instead, that will not involve so much code duplication?

Comment: Not really addressing indices trick, but most of this code seems to be redundant. Neither `unordered_map` or `input_buffer_name` are necessary as you are essentially extract `memory_region` items using index. So it seems to me that you can use `tuple` as container. Moreover, if `Ts` pack does not contain duplicated types then you can use tagged tuple as container and extract items from it directly by type. `compute_stuff_with_buffers(regions.at<Ts>().as_span<Ts>()...);`

Comment: @VTT: The code which creates `my_map` doesn't know which types the code which uses `my_map` is going to be interested in. Also, Ts often contains duplicate types. Will edit to mention this last point.

Comment: @VTT: Also, other parts of the code need to be able to iterate through `buffers` without knowing the types of anything, and with `buffers` originating from different instantiations.

Comment: Small request: Can you fix the syntax errors in your code, and also link to a compileable example? Will really help those coming here to quickly get up to speed and answer your question faster.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use simple pack expansion in the form of an array:

```
template<typename... Ts>
void my_function(std::unordered_map<std::string, memory_region>& my_map) {
    using swallow = int[];
    unsigned i = 0;
    (void)swallow{0, (my_map.at(input_buffer_name(i++)).as_span<Ts>(), 0)...};
}
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/umx9DmdK46atiTKc)

The pack expansion will be expanded in order ([temp.variadic]), and also evaluated in order (left to right) because we're using a braced initializer list (an unused integer array): [dcl.init.aggr]

> When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list [...] the elements of the initializer list are taken as initializers for the elements of the aggregate, in order.

---

Re:

> But what if I need to use input_buffer_name(i) twice? e.g. if I need to use 
>   `{ input_buffer_name(index), my_map.at(input_buffer_name(index).as_span<Ts>()) }`

I suppose we could take advantage of the fact that logical AND will sequence left to right ([expr.log.and]), and also a boolean can be promoted to `int`:

```
template<typename... Ts>
void my_function_v2(std::unordered_map<std::string, memory_region>& my_map) {
    using swallow = int[];
    unsigned i = 0;
    (void)swallow{0, ((std::cout<< input_buffer_name(i) << std::endl, true) && (my_map.at(input_buffer_name(i++)).as_span<Ts>(), true))...};
}
```

#### [Demo 2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/g4P2HSofeFdoPWUC)

Comment: This works, so +1, but it now about about half as clunky as the helper function way.

Comment: @einpoklum: IMO the helper function is not so terrible. Maybe we could investigate creating a generate helper function that everyone can call?