# Ellipsis appears in a parameter declaration of a template function

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

This is the example from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). I don't understand how the pattern get expanded.

```
template<typename ...Ts, int... N> void g(Ts (&...arr)[N]) {}
int n[1];
g<const char, int>("a", n); // Ts (&...arr)[N] expands to 
                            // const char (&)[2], int(&)[1]

Note: In the pattern Ts (&...arr)[N], the ellipsis is the innermost element, not the last element as in all other pack expansions.
```

Question 1: what is arr?

Question 2: n is a int array, does it match to int...N?

Question 3: How come it can expand to const char (&)[2], int(&)[1]

Comment: See any number of questions about pack expansion, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26767333/2069064)

Comment: To address question 2: `Ts` is a type pack for the array types, and `N` is an int pack for the array dimensions, so `n` provides the type `int` into the `Ts` pack, and the dimension 1 into the `N` pack.

Comment: Ugly syntax of reference to C-Array (`int (&a)[42]` ) with variadic template.

Comment: For 3: "a" is equivalent to { 'a', 0 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whereas

```
template <typename ...Ts> void f(Ts&...arr);
```

is mostly equivalent to

```
template <typename T0, typename T1, .., typename TN>
void f(T0& arr0, T1& arr1, .., TN& arrN);
```

for any `N`.

In the same way,

```
template <typename ...Ts, int... Ns> void g(Ts (&...arr)[Ns]);
```

would be equivalent to

```
template <typename T0, typename T1, .., typename TN, int N0, int N1, .. int NN>
void g(T0 (&arr0)[N0], T1 (&arr1)[N1], .., TN (&arrN)[NN]);
```

and type `T (&)[N]` is a reference to C-array of size `N` with element of type `T`

`int n[1];` is trivially of type `int [1]`.

`"a"` is of type `const char[2]` (`{'a', '\0'}`).

Comment: A: void g(T0 (&arr0)[N0], T1 (&arr1)[N1], .., TN (&arrN)[NN]);

B: g<const char, int>("a", n);

I can understand your answer, but how does A match to B? Thanks

Comment: So if T0 = const char and T1 = int, what are N0 and N1? Where do the 2 and 1 come from in the expanded result?

Comment: @Jerry: Edited. `"a"` is not `const char*` but `const char[2]`.

Comment: Is this a specific structure of the command? Like why can't `void g(Ts... (&)[Ns...])` or `void g(Ts (&)[Ns]...)` work? Can you explain how both the options are wrong. I'm pretty new to it.

Comment: @Dhruv: It is mostly a syntax/grammar issue; syntax for c-array (and function) is *"ugly"*.BTW, `Ts... (&)[Ns...]` would have 2 distinct packs :/ . Using alias might help when working with c-array: `template <typename T, std::size_t N>using CArray = T[N];` then `CArray<Ts, Ns>&...arr` is the way to go.