# Type function that returns a tuple of chosen types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

I've implemented a type function `Tuple` that turn a list of `My_enum` values into an `std::tuple` of corresponding types:

```
#include <tuple>

enum My_enum{ t_int, t_double };

// Bind_type is a type function that given a My_enum returns the corresponding type
template<My_enum E> struct Bind_type;
template<> struct Bind_type<t_int>{ using type = int; };
template<> struct Bind_type<t_double>{ using type = double; };

// Tuple is a type function that given a template value parameter pack of My_enums returns a std::tuple of correspondig types
template<My_enum First, My_enum... Others>
struct Tuple {
    using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(
                typename Tuple<First>::type{},
                typename Tuple<Others...>::type{}
            ));
};

template<>
struct Tuple<t_int> {
    using type = std::tuple<Bind_type<t_int>::type>;
};
template<>
struct Tuple<t_double> {
    using type = std::tuple<Bind_type<t_double>::type>;
};
```

I'd like to be able to declare the recursion base case for `Tuple` in one shot, because I don't want to manually manage `Tuple` specialization as long as I add or remove values to `My_enum`, because it is error prone (and boring). I've tried:

```
template<My_enum E>
struct Tuple {
    using type = std::tuple<Bind_type<E>::type>;
};
```

but this is not a valid specialization for the variadic version.

My question is: is there a smart way to declare the specialization of `Tuple` when it has only one template value parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this without recursion by simply expanding the parameter pack directly into a `std::tuple`:

```
template<My_enum... Enums>
struct Tuple {
    using type = std::tuple<typename Bind_type<Enums>::type...>;
};
```

To answer your question more directly, you can declare a variadic primary template, then write two specializations: for when there are at least two parameters, and for when there is only one:

```
//primary template, takes any number of My_enums
template <My_enum... Enums>
struct Tuple {
    //this case will be chosen if we instantiate a Tuple with no args
    using type = std::tuple<>;
}

//specialization for when there are at least two arguments
template<My_enum First, My_enum Second, My_enum... Others>
struct Tuple<First,Second,Others...> {
    using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(
                typename Tuple<First>::type{},
                typename Tuple<Second,Others...>::type{}
            ));
};

//base case, only one argument left
template<My_enum Last>
struct Tuple<Last> {
    using type = std::tuple<typename Bind_type<Last>::type>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for both the answers :). Didn't know I could expand the parameter pack that way and very very interesting the trick of two parameters before the variadic ones.

Comment: I found this question really helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652412/what-are-the-rules-for-the-token-in-the-context-of-variadic-template. The answers explain the proper use and use cases of the elipsis (...) in variadic templates.

Comment: Note that the zero-pack-sized case fails to work with the #2 solution above.  You also need the `<>` specialization, which can also be put in the primary specialization.