# C++ expand parameter pack to tuple of arrays

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I would like to instantiate a class *like*

```
template<typename ...Args>
class X {
private:
    std::tuple<std::array<Arg0, 255>, std::array<Arg1, 255>, ...> m_tuples; // For Arg in Args
}
```

I know this is not correct C++, but how could I achieve the effect of expanding the parameter pack template of the class to the arrays held within the tuple?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
template<typename ...Args>
class X {
private:
    std::tuple<std::array<Args, 255>...> m_tuples; // For Arg in Args
};
```

... you didn't expect to be so close, did you :)

Comment: I did not! Can you explain how this expansion works? I am stuck thinking about this as I would recursive function calls, popping off the first element of the parameter pack.

Comment: @shane The rules are a bit fuzzy for me, but in short pack expansion works by duplicating a (syntactic) pattern and replacing the argument packs within this pattern. Here the pattern is the whole `std::array<Args, 255>`, which gets expanded to what you are after by replacing `Args`.

Comment: @shane See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652412/what-are-the-rules-for-the-token-in-the-context-of-variadic-templates.