# Is it possible to make a function that handles unlimited arguments with different type of variables?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make some magic function that can handle unlimited arguments(like in printf) and different types, like:

```cpp
MagicFun(signed int(-1), "Hello!", __int16(200), glm::vec2(2, 2));
```

And I want that function to detect the type of it like if its int, const char* or vec2/3... and I want to get the values of them.

Is it really possible? I heard about `template <typename T>` but I am in a confusion about how do I use it. Thanks.

Comment: You could use a [variadic template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Comment: Yes, you can. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack.

Comment: Reading more about templates might be a good start, because then you can continue to *template parameter packs* which could help solve your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the rules for the "..." token in the context of variadic templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652412/what-are-the-rules-for-the-token-in-the-context-of-variadic-templates)